# Efficiently count list entries that are smaller than a given value

Tags: python, performance, list, python-2.7

I have two lists, one contains employee salaries and one contains queries. For each query I want to print how many employee salaries are less than that.

Below you can find code I currently use, which exceeds my time limit for large inputs. Therefore, I'm looking for more efficient solutions.

```
sal = [int(raw_input()) for x in range(num_employees)]
q = [int(raw_input()) for x in range(num_queries)]
for i in q:
    count = 0
    for ep in sal:
        if ep < i:
            count +=1
    print count
```

Comment: You could take a look at SQL-Databases, like [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: If you are using `raw_input()` to obtain your data in the first place, I would think that takes much longer than the actual double loop. How do you enter the data into your program?

Comment: I get input as integers. First the number of employees then there values.

Comment: How many items and what time limit are we talking about? For questions regarding performance optimization it is generally advisable to use a profiler to identify the actual slow part of the application. Try cProfile and gprof2dot.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether this will be any faster (or slower) than your solution. You can use the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/timeit.html#module-timeit) module to determine with your large inputs.

```
sal = [int(raw_input()) for x in range(num_employees)]
q = [int(raw_input()) for x in range(num_queries)]
for i in q:
   print sum(1 for s in sal if s < i)
```

Depending on data sizes, you could sort the salaries and queries beforehand and then you only need make one pass over the lists:

```
idx = 0
sal = sorted(sal)
count = 0
for q in sorted(queries):
    while sal[idx] < q:
        count += 1
        idx += 1
    print count
```

This second method will be faster for long inputs, but perhaps slower for shorter inputs - you'd have to profile with representative data. If your data is already sorted this method will be very fast.

Answer (score 1):

```
sal = [int(raw_input()) for x in range(num_employees)]
q = [int(raw_input()) for x in range(num_queries)]
for i in q:
    count = sum([1 for for ep in sal if ep < i])
    print count
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `bisect` on a sorted `sal` list:

```
import bisect

sal = [int(raw_input()) for x in range(num_employees)]
q = [int(raw_input()) for x in range(num_queries)]
sal.sort()
for i in q:
    print bisect.bisect_left(sal, i)
```

`bisect` does a logarithmic search, where the largest element of `sal < i` is. For large lists, the complexity is `O(N * log(N))` instead of `O(N ** 2)` for the other solution with two for-loops. This is considerably faster for large numbers `N`.